# my ajax wont execute my controller

Tags: java, ajax, spring

i tried accessing my controller through ajax to get DB results but it wont work. The ajax is inside a submit button and executes well without the ajax. The code is supposed to execute a query and check if the input exists. 
Here's my ajax

```js
var jsonData = {
    "appname": appname,
    "txtype": txtype,
    "ipaddress": ipaddress
   };
   $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: "checkaccesspermission.html",
     data: jsonData,
     success: function(data) {
     if(data == "exists"){
      alert('Permission Already Exists!');
      return false;
     }else{
      alert('Add Permission test Succesful!');
      return true; 
     }
    },
     async: false
   });
```

here's my controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/checkaccesspermission", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String checkaccesspermission(@ModelAttribute("loginForm") IpAccessManagementModel loginForm, Model model,
            @RequestParam("ipaddress") String ipaddress,
            @RequestParam("txtypeHidden") String txtype,
            @RequestParam("appIDHidden") String appID) throws IOException{
            System.out.println("CHECKACCESSPERMISSIONs");
            IpAccessManagementModel sub = new IpAccessManagementModel();

            //System.out.println("<script language='JavaScript'>alert('Hello');</script>");
            sub.setAppName(appID);
            sub.setTxtType(txtype);
            sub.setIpAddress(ipaddress);
            System.out.println(ipaddress);
            ipAccessMGTDAO.addPermission(sub);
            String resultCheckExist = ipAccessMGTDAO.checkAccessPermission(sub);
            return resultCheckExist;
    }
```

Comment: You're sending a `POST` request and your method is mapped on `GET` method.

Comment: Url passed to ajax call is not correct, remove the extension . html and add /checkaccesspermission with GET request. Make sure you are using correct http method.

Comment: Thanks for the input! i tried both your solutions and it worked.

Comment: I'm having a problem regarding this, it executes the query and everything, but it wont fetch the return type of my controller :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the .html extension and Change your method annotation in the controller to method=RequestMethod.POST
also remove

```
@RequestParam("ipaddress") String ipaddress,
@RequestParam("txtypeHidden") String txtype,
@RequestParam("appIDHidden") String appID
```

because its a Post request

Comment: done :) i did upvote but my reputation is too low for it to show :(

Comment: thank you... yes u can't update but you can select the answer as accepted .. the green tick.. that will help

Comment: I'm having a problem regarding this, it executes the query and everything, but it wont fetch the return type of my controller :(

Comment: will you post your result and what do you want

Comment: It prints everything from the controller that is being called, executes the query as well. But the function inside "Success" won't execute and i'm not sure why. I want the alert to execute and based on my controller prints, the return type of my controller is exactly the one I want which isn't being fetched by the success function from the ajax. It also goes to the "error" handler which prints nothing.